# Problem formulating a question involving a binomial random variable.

Tags: matlab, binomial-distribution

I want to write a question which involves the use of a binomial random variable. This is it.

"A student wants to pass a subject with 100 lessons studying the minimum possible. The exam is composed of three questions chosen randomly from an urn which contains 100 numerated balls. The three balls correspond to the lessons of which, the student has to choose one.

Calculate the amount of lessons that the student has to study so that he has a probability equal or higher to 0.95 of extracting at least one ball corresponding to a known subject"

To solve this problem, I want to say

P=1-[binopdf](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/binopdf.html)(0, 3, p) and having to find out p using a for loop.

However, if I left the question as written, a binomial would not model my problem properly, since after the first pick, the second would be done with a sample of 99 and the third with a sample of 98 balls.

Can someone please tell me how to rewrite this question so that it can be modelled using a binomial random variable?

Comment: To solve the problem as you described, you should use hypergeometric distribution, instead of binominal distribution.

Comment: @user295357 Thanks. That's what I feared. If it were possible, could you suggest me a way of modifiyng the question so that the binomial can be used?